# Can't achieve CSS clip-path animation and responsiveness at the same time

Tags: css, svg, responsive, clip-path

I have an element on my page that needs to have its `clip-path` shape animated. For reference, this is for a draggable carousel.

While the carousel is being dragged, I would like its `clip-path` to change from a `clip-path` that looks like a rectangle to one that has curved sides. I also need this element to be responsive and have a changing size, and that's where I get stuck - I can't seem to make a transforming/animating `clip-path` that is also responsive.

If I use `clip-path` with path syntax, `CSS` can handle this animation. I've set up an example only with a hover state, to show that this works.

```
<div class="testshape"><div>
.testshape {
    clip-path: path("m 37,0 h 535 c 0,0 0.21081,92.5 0.21081,238 C 572.21081,383.5 572,476 572,476 H 37 C 37,476 35.688413,367.39046 35.688413,239.39046 35.688413,111.39046 37,0 37,0 Z");
    
    background-color:red;
    transition: all .2s;
    aspect-ratio: 572/476;
    width :100%;

    &:hover {
        clip-path: path("M37 0H572C572 0 549.5 92.5 549.5 238C549.5 383.5 572 476 572 476H37C37 476 0 366 0 238C0 110 37 0 37 0Z");
    }
}
```

However - I can't make this clip-path shape responsive.

I can make the clip-path shape responsive by using an inline SVG with

```
clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
```

but if I do that, CSS won't handle the transform between url(#shape) style clip paths. They change instantly as it switches to the new clipPath ID.

For reference, that looks like this (using some simplified shapes):

```
<div class="testshape"><div>

                <svg width="0" height="0">
                    <defs>
                        <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                            <polygon points="0 1, 0 0, 1 0, 0.8 1" />
                        </clipPath>

                        <clipPath id="clip-shape-2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                            <polygon points="0 .5, 0 0, 1 0, 0.1 .5" />
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                </svg>

.testshape {
    clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
    
    background-color:red;
    transition: all .2s;
    aspect-ratio: 572/476;
    width :100%;

    &:hover {
       clip-path: url("#clip-shape-1");
    }
}
```

Though having an inline SVG gives me more control over the SVG properties including how it handles aspect ratio changes, my understanding is **I can't animate this transition** because the CSS can't actually animate any values since all it sees are IDs.

I can make a responsive, animated clip path shape if I use a polygon with percentage values, but I can't then have a curved shape as one of my clip-paths. Since curves can't exist in polygons.

I'm stumped on a solution to this problem. Is there a wasy to use relative, percentage based values in the 'path' syntax for clip-path? My core goal is to transition a rectangular shape to a curved shape with a smooth animation.

Update: In the end, I made use of GSAP's MorphSVG plugin and masking to do what I wanted.

Comment: How responsive it need to be? A boring but practical solution might be having a few pre-defined shapes (and hover shapes) that matches a few  pre-defined screen sizes.

Comment: The aspect ratio of the block will be the same at all times, but unfortunately it needs to be fluidly responsive in terms of width - eg. this block will take up 30% of the container width at any given time. I'm tied to a provided design so I can't change that unfortunately.

Comment: Show us the url clipPath code.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have updated my question with an example - but I know I can't use CSS to animate URL based clip paths.

Comment: You can use SMIL instead.